# How can I open multiple minibuffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Say I'm entering a command in the minibuffer, and I realize that I need to remember the path to some file as a param to my command. Can I instead of cancelling the command I started entering to do C-x d or to go to a shell, click (click? what's that?) on a secondary mini buffer to run such command?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you try ido if you are annoyed that you have to remember the path. And as a bonus, you can type `C-d` when you still need to open dired after `C-x C-f` has been typed(and you are in minibuffer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for ["recursive editing"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Editing.html), specifically the bit discussed in the [Recursive Minibuffer docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Mini.html):

```
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode 1)
```

The latter line makes things the recursive editing less confusing, by showing the level of recursion. E.g `C-x C-f` then `C-x b` will appear like this:

[image: minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode example]

Comment: You absolutely positively also want `(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode 1)` to go along with that.

Comment: @phils That's great, definitely makes things less confusing - mentioned it in the answer

Comment: When I start with a `ido-find-file` and continue with `ido-switch-buffer` there is no minibuffer depth indication. When I start with `file-cache-ido-find-file` and continue with `ido-switch-buffer` there is an indicator... anyone got an idea how to fix this? Because I've been longing for that feature since.... forever!